# and (&&) of pointers in cpp

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to know the difference between `if(left && right)` and `if(left != NULL && right != NULL)`

I was writing program for lowest common ancestor of binary tree , they both are not NULL wouldn't there 
and(`&&`) be 1 that is (`left && right == 1`) But I am getting wrong answer for this .

On the other hand `if(left!=NULL && right != NULL)` working fine.

I am new to cpp PLease forgive me if question is too silly.

problem Link [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/lowest-common-ancestor-of-a-binary-tree/submissions/)

Test cases in which failing

[3,5,1,6,2,0,8,null,null,7,4] it is preorder  traversal from leetcode

5

4

```
TreeNode* lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* p, TreeNode* q) {
    if(root==NULL||root==p||root==q)return root;
    TreeNode* left = lowestCommonAncestor(root->left,p,q);
    TreeNode* right = lowestCommonAncestor(root->right,p,q);
    if(!left && !right)return NULL;

    if(left && root)return root;
   // if(left != NULL && right != NULL) return root;  
    return left == NULL ? right : left;
}
```

Comment: There's no difference apart from verbosity...

Comment: Prefer `nullptr` over `NULL`.

Comment: Operator precedence: your `left && right == 1` example is equivalent to `left && (right == 1)`. You don't need the `== 1` part anyway, since it won't be any value except `1` or `0`. Just use `left && right` if you want to shorten it.

Comment: The `if` statement checks if the expression evaluates to 0. Since `NULL` expands to 0 you are doing things twice, but I'm pretty sure the compiler removes it

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/fr2cMsW Please see this

Comment: There is also a *possible* confusion between `right` and `root` in the code you show: compare `if(left && root)return root;` with the commented-out line, `if(left != NULL && right != NULL) return root;`.

Comment: `left && root` is the same as `left != NULL && root != NULL`  (which is not the same as `(left != NULL && right != NULL)` -- obviously?)

Comment: So, is root right or right right? ‎

Comment: Thanks and sorry everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply because your below two statements are not equivalent:

```
if(left && root)return root;
// if(left != NULL && right != NULL) return root;
```

In first line you check for ***left and root*** and in second line you check for ***left and right***.

P.S. ***(left)*** and ***(left != NULL)*** are equivalent